# Configurations for a NxM grid?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given a N by M grid, there can be an item on each point of the grid. The possible configurations for this situation is just $2^{NM}$, because each point either does or does not have an item in it. But now, imagine each item can be one of three items: apple, orange, pear. What is the number of possible configurations for this setup?

My original intuition is for it to be $2^{NM} * 3$ because every item that are in the grid can be one of three choices, but this doesn't check out when I try it out on the base cases.

Any hints to go towards the right direction?

Comment: How many possibilities for one particular square?  Now multiply them together as you did for one kind of item.

Comment: Alright so we have four possibilities for one square: no item, apple, orange, or pear. That makes it $4^{NM}$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct